# How to put button under an image? Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

Hello guys im new in flutter and i need help with my app, to put a button under an image in my app main menu,

here is my code so far i build based on https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/tutorial

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'images/MenuImg.jpg',
              width: 600,
              height: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what i wanna do is put a button to navigate to a different page.

Here is a little illustration where i want to put my button

[image: Here is a little illustration where i want to put my button, thanks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the widget `Column` in the body argument of your `Scaffold` widget to have the possibility to add multiple widgets in a column view on your screen.

You can find a fully working example at this [zaap.run link](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zf6060ef706?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart).

You can also find the code without any preview here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://i.imgur.com/9ZOaH1m.jpeg',
                width: 600,
                height: 200,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button1"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button2"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button3"),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello sir, i find ur code fit my app well, but can u tell me how can i move the button a bit down? because when i run it, the button is very close to the image. thank you

Comment: Hello @NyK, you can use the widget `SizedBox()` and a height property to make a space between your `Stack()` widget and your `Row()` of buttons inside your `Column()`

Answer (score 3):

Just change the `Stack` with Column or Listiw

```
body: Column(
 children: [
  Image.asset(
    'images/MenuImg.jpg',
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  /// your button is here:
  Row(
  children:[
  ElevetedButton(),// btn 1
  ElevetedButton(),// btn 2
  ... 
 ],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the image widget with a `Column`, to set widgets ordered vertically, I did it for the Row to show the button with a `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to space them

Give it a try this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/MenuImg.jpg',
                  width: 600,
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('btn 1'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('btn 2'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('btn 3'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/MenuImg.jpg',
                  width: 600,
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
                          body: body,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 2'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
                          body: body,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 3'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
                          body: body,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```